# Excel launches blank from any location, loading the file a second time works

Tags: microsoft-excel

Bit of a strange issue here, when launching a file from any location in Excel, the contents will not display, only a blank page.
Loading the file a second time, or launching the file once a blank excel has been loaded first will then display the contents.

I looked into this issue and found this:

Location: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office<version>\Excel\Security
Name: WorkbookLinkWarnings
Value type: DWORD
Value: 2

But this did not exist as a location and manually doing it did not work.

There is a frame. Also then selecting "OPEN" and selecting the file will work, just any excel file containing data will open a blank excel.

Comment: So if you launch an excel file from the desktop or windows explorer, with Excel fully closed beforehand, you just get a blank workbook? What version of Excel are you using? Do you perhaps have multiple versions, or had say Excel 2016 ship with your computer (as a demo), but installed Excel 2013 with license afterwards?

Comment: Perhaps try holding shift while launching Excel (launches Excel in safe-mode).

Comment: To clarify - when you first open Excel, instead of seeing a blank workbook or the file you're opening, you see an empty Excel frame?

Comment: Sorry its, a blank workbook with a frame.

Comment: I occasionally have the same problem and have not been able to fix it. For a while it happened most of the time, but has been better lately. Today my outlook stopped working, so I completely uninstalled and reinstalled Office. Maybe that will help the Excel issue.